# Differences between times in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I am trying to figure out the difference between two times within a current timezone. I'm trying to figure out whether to call a support telephone number between two times. I.e., I am using the `active_support` gem and I want to do something like

- `t` = current time
- `o` = open time according to current date (9AM)
- `c` = close time according to current date (5PM)
- `call_open` = are we open?

Would someone be able to help?

Comment: I think you can use [between?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-between-3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do

`call_open = t.between?(o, c)`

Comment: thanks json. how would I represent `o` and `c` using `active_support` - i.e. at time on the current day of `9am`

Comment: Are you asking about "9am today" and "5pm today?" I guess you could do `Time.zone.today.midnight + 9.hours` and `Time.zone.today.midnight + 17.hours`.

Comment: (Although I bet there's a better way that I don't know about.)

Answer (score 0):

```
t = Time.zone.now
o = Time.zone.today + 8.hours
c = Time.zone.today + 17.hours
call_open = t <= c && t >= o
```

Comment: thanks daniel. i am using `active_support` so I need to ensure its in the current timezone ? i.e. like `Time.zone.now`

Comment: Edited, I don't prefer that explicitness, but you can use it.

Comment: Can `call_open` use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-between-3F ?

Comment: No problem with that at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time to create ranges, which allows easy testing for inclusion:

```
t1 = Time.now
sleep 1
t2 = Time.now
sleep 1
t3 = Time.now

(t1.to_i .. t3.to_i) === t2.to_i # => true
(t1.to_f .. t3.to_f) === t2.to_f # => true
(t1.to_f .. t2.to_f) === t3.to_f # => false
```

You can use parsing to figure it out:

```
starttime = Time.parse('2013/01/24 9AM')                               # => 2013-01-24 09:00:00 -0700
endtime = Time.parse('2013/01/24 5PM')                                 # => 2013-01-24 17:00:00 -0700
(starttime.to_f .. endtime.to_f) === Time.parse('2013/01/24 3PM').to_f # => true
```

And you can work with hours only, which makes it date agnostic:

```
(t1.hour .. t3.hour) === t2.hour # => true
```